# How do you switch ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I currently have two ViewControllers (2 `.h`, `.m`, and `.xib` files) and would like to switch them when a button is pressed (namely the Options button.)
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm trying to make the screen switch to the `Options.xib` file but am not sure how to do this.
(The `.pngs` are just the launch images.) I am not very experienced in Objective-C (full code would be appreciated.) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import "OptionViewController.h"


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [optionsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    OptionViewController *vc = [[OptionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
}
```

Comment: What file would this go in?

Comment: This needs to go into the implementation file (the .m file) for whichever view controller is on the screen and contains the button for which you want to connect this action. You will also need code to attach the action to the button (I'll edit my answer).

Comment: Would it help that the button is referred to as optionsButton

Comment: Updated code. BTW if you already have an implementation of viewDidLoad, just add the optionsButton line to it. My example above just shows the minimum code you should have.

Comment: It gives me this on the line [optionsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];: No visible @interface for UIButton declares the sector addTarget:action

Comment: oops I forgot a parameter... one moment

Comment: Thank you so much, my friend and I were wondering for quite a bit of time :)

Comment: Cool. Be sure to read over the UIViewController and UIButton documentation!

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl drag` from the button to the `Options View Controller` and chose `modal`.